# Install Ubuntu 14.04 to replace 12.10, as dual boot with Windows.

Tags: 14.04

I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 to replace 12.10, as dual boot with Windows. A straight install (option "Something Else") would not run, so I installed 14.04 "alongside Windows". But it did not delete 12.1, so now I have both versions on the computer.  Installing alongside Windows does not give a choice of where to install it.
Version 12.1 is on a separate partition of a 2nd hard drive. I'm afraid I don't fully understand the Ubuntu partitions, so that could contribute to the problem.

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL` from the new installation

Comment: Here is the output of that command:

Comment: Output of command:

sda                                     931.5G
           sda1          vfat         8.5G                  
 sdb                                     232.9G
            sdb1        vfat           8.5G
            sdb2         ntfs           112.2G
            sdb3                          1k
            sdb5         ext4          57.7G
            sdb6        swap              2G      [swap]
            ssdb7        ext4           52.6G      /
            sr0                             1024M
            sr1                              1024M

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to upgrade your version from within: I've done this before, sadly you do need to upgrade one version at a time.

From what I recall anyway, here's a link: [Upgrade to the Latest Ubuntu the Easy Way](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/31688/upgrade-to-the-latest-ubuntu-the-easy-way/)

Hopefully you can sort it out.

Comment: BACKUP YOUR USER DATA FIRST!!!!

Comment: Please do not post links to external sources, rather describe the answer here.

Comment: Well it's a trusted source but mmmmOkay :/

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, you are installing, not upgrading. You are deleting 12.10 and installing 14.04. This is what you need to do in "Something Else"

1. Boot your 14.04 install image from your cd/usb.
2. After selecting the option "Something Else" you need to delete your 12.02 Ubuntu partitions and designate new partitions for your 14.04 install.
3. The minimum you will need is the root '/' partition and swap area. Depending if your machine is UEFI bootable, you may require an EFI boot partition also.
4. The root partition is the uppermost level of pathname of your whole operating system. If you did not designate a home partition, the root partition will contain your home files in the same partition.
5. The swap area is like your Windows page file. A good starting point for deciding how much you need is to match it with your RAM.
6. The EFI boot partition is required if your computer has UEFI boot enabled. No configuring is required for this one, you just have to have it if you have UEFI enabled.
7. Once you have root, swap, and EFI, then you can install your system.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have already done it wrong, where should I start? Should I uninstall 14.04 first, then run the 14.04 install disc? Should I uninstall 12.10?  If I uninstall, will it fix (or delete) the partition? I don't want to mess things up & not even be able to boot Windows, or some such problem. When I first used "Something Else", that's what happened, because it couldn't find Grub.